# Make fancybox jQuery plugin with results from submitting a form on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-plugins, fancybox

I am trying to take form results that are generated from a PHP call and populate them into a div that will then appear in a light box upon click of the submit button.  So far I have successfully setup the form and am populating the results on the same page into a hidden div.  I can make this div appear no problem in a light box by setting up a href link but cannot make it show up by simply by clicking the submit button.  I know my fancybox and jQuery calls are good but not sure where I'm going wrong on the submit button.

Here is what I have so far to make it work with a link:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#various1").fancybox({
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none',
            'scrolling'         : 'auto',
            'overlayOpacity'    : '0'
        });
    });
    </script>
<a id="various1" href="#inline1" >Inline</a>    
<div style="display: none;">
    <div id="inline1" style="width:500px;height:550px;">
```

Works great here when you click inline after I have submitted the form.

Here is what I tried to make it work with the submit button:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submit").click(function(){

    alert('jQTest');
    $("#various1").fancybox();

    }); 
});

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="--> Find" />
```

I think it has to be some way I'm calling the jQuery for the fancybox or some identifier for the submit button & div because the submit button click is registering fine.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$("#submit").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //alert('jQTest');
    $("#various1").fancybox();

    }); 
});
```

Comment: I need to change the link id or the div id somehow to match the fancybox call.  You will see that #various1 calls to the <a> I have setup.

Comment: I was referring more to the `e.preventDefault()` function. One of the reasons it isn't working is because clicking a submit button unloads the page, rendering javascript useless. That function stops the click from submitting the form.

Comment: k I see a ajax call function as a part of fancybox.  I should probably investigate it a little more.